# Net461 issue: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I've made a custom logging provider as a nuget package so I can save down exceptions and unique data to a database.
I have published this to devops and I've installed it in the main project that needs to use it.
When I now start up the main project I get a "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" error.

I've tried using different versions of all the logging nuget packages that has Abstractions but it doesnt seem to work, if I downgrade below 3.0.0 then I need to rewrite my logging provider which I dont want to do

I have already looked around a lot and tried the different solutions in the other StackOverflow questions but none of them are working.

Both the nuget package and the main project is running net461

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look inside your `.config` file. Is there an entry for your library? It can sometimes happen that a change is needed in the `.config` to get it working.

Comment: I was missing a nuget reference to said package in the startup project, thanks for guiding me in the right direction!